# Deduction List - ASP Arrays

Tags: asp-classic

I want to display a breakdown of total investment deductions as an array list. The total amount of **deductions** is $-20.24 and my list breakdown is not adding up to that amount. I'm not too sure where I got it wrong. Please review my code and provide feedback. See total value being returned below:

```
Date         Units   Unit price       Value
30/04/2018  -4.203   $ 1.99143     $ -8.37  
30/04/2018  -0.366   $ 1.99454     $ -0.73  
30/04/2018  -1.576   $ 3.54061     $ -5.58  
30/04/2018  -0.138   $ 3.55072     $ -0.49  
30/04/2018  -1.871   $ 2.49065     $ -4.66  
30/04/2018  -0.164   $ 2.50000     $ -0.41  
Total amount                          $ 16.98

<%
Dim objMemberClient, SwitchList
set objMemberClient = Server.createObject("MemberServiceProxy")

SwitchList=   objMemberClient.GetInvestmentTransactionObjList(session("MemberId"),session("FundCode"), request.Querystring("date"), request.Querystring("date"), request.Querystring("description"))
%>

<h1>Investments</h1>
<div class="table-responsive">
<%if request.Querystring("description") = "Deduction" then %>
    <TABLE class="table">
        <%for i = LBound(SwitchList) to UBound(SwitchList)%>    
        <%if SwitchList(i).DeductionCode =   getDesc(request.Querystring("subtype")) then%>
    <tr>    
            <%if SwitchList(i).DeductionSign = true then%>
                    <td class="table_Header" width="200px">Investment sold</td>
                    <%exit for%>

            <%end if%>
        <%end if%>
        <%Next%>
            <td class="table_Header" width="125px">Date</td>
            <td class="table_Header" width="125px">Units</td>
            <td class="table_Header" width="125px">Unit price</td>
            <td class="table_Header" width="125px">Value</td>
        </tr>
        <%for i = LBound(SwitchList) to UBound(SwitchList)%>    
        <%if SwitchList(i).DeductionCode =  getDesc(request.Querystring("subtype")) then%>
    <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="border_Bottom"> <%=SwitchList(i).InvestmentOption.Name%></td>
                <td valign="top" class="border_Bottom"><%=SwitchList(i).InvestmentDate%></td>
                <td valign="top" class="border_Bottom"> <%=SwitchList(i).NumberUnits%></td>
            <%if SwitchList(i).DeductionSign = true then %>
                <%total = total + SwitchList(i).SwitchOutDollarValue%>
                <%total = total * -1%>
                <td valign="top" class="border_Bottom">$&nbsp;<%=FormatNumber(SwitchList(i).SwitchOutDollarValue/Replace(SwitchList(i).NumberUnits,"-",""),5)%></td>
            <td valign="top" class="border_Bottom">$&nbsp;-<%=FormatNumber(SwitchList(i).SwitchOutDollarValue,2)%></td> 

                 <%end if%>
    </TABLE>
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out `total = total * -1` ?

Comment: As @SearchAndResQ eludes to: 8.37 - 0.73 + 5.58 - 0.49 + 4.66 - 0.41 = 16.98

Comment: If someone answered your question you mark one as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to debug if we had something we could execute, but just guessing I think your problem is here:

```
<%total = total + SwitchList(i).SwitchOutDollarValue%>
<%total = total * -1%>
```

`Total` is a negative value, SwitchOutDollarValue I believe is a positive value, so comibining them in this way is not going to get the result you want.

As @SearchAndResQ mentioned, I would remove `<%total = total * -1%>` from inside the `for` loop and move it to just before you display the total.